# How to display cpu usage respectively?

Tags: cpu, top

Here is my cpu part of info(omitted unnecessary).

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1840 @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x19
cpu MHz     : 2800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
```

There two cpus in my pc.
`top` command can display cpus usage as a whole.
How to display cpu1 usage and cpu2 usage respectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toggle 'single CPU' mode inside `top` by hitting the `1` key. From `man top`:

```
       Summary-Area-defaults
          l - Load Avg/Uptime  On  (thus program name)
          t - Task/Cpu states  On  (1+1 lines, see `1')
          m - Mem/Swap usage   On  (2 lines worth)
          1 - Single Cpu       Off (thus multiple cpus)
```

For example, with single CPU 'on' (the default, apparently):

```
top - 22:42:17 up 1 day,  1:11,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.20
Tasks: 225 total,   1 running, 224 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.3 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3936368 total,   293968 free,  2812496 used,   829904 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1512244 total,  1247116 free,   265128 used.   419072 avail Mem
```

after pressing `1`:

```
top - 22:45:40 up 1 day,  1:14,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.11, 0.18
Tasks: 225 total,   2 running, 223 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  1.6 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.9 id,  0.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.8 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3936368 total,   283964 free,  2813716 used,   838688 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1512244 total,  1247176 free,   265068 used.   414712 avail Mem
```

You can create/update your `~/.toprc` file to make this the default by hitting `W`.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical**

- Open System Monitor in your computer which fulfills your requirement

[image]

**Command Line**

- Simply press 1 followed by top command to toggle to multiple cpu mode